# How does 2 dimensional space transforms in 3-harmonic-oscillators problem?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I'm reading *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics* by Howard Georgi. When talking about an example of harmonic oscillator (on Page 27), it says

> "The 2 dimensional space transforms by the representation $D_2$ below"

and then gives a unitary irreducible representation of $S_3$. I'm puzzled about what happened here. How does this representation come out? Is that a subgroup of $SO(2)$?

[image: representation of D2]

Comment: *Is that a subgroup of $SO(2)$?* Do you know what 2D rotation matrices look like? Do all of these have that form?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. What I'm thinking is whether these first 3 representations are connected with some rotation transformations. And it seems that these last 3 are something to do with rotation+reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke Cayley's Theorem, which states that every group is isomorphic to a permutation group. Following that, if we consider the symmetry group of an equilateral triangle, which is isomorphic to $S_{3}$, the permutation group of order three. For a chemist $S_{3}$ is the symmetry group of the Ammonia.

The group elements are $\{E,R_{1},R_{2},R_{3},R_{4},R_{4}\}$, where $E$ is the identity element, $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ rotate the triangle by the angle $2\pi/3$ and $4\pi/3$ about the $z-$ axis, respectively. The remaining operations $R_3$, $R_4$, and $R_5$ denote reflections at the axes. Pictorially,
[image]

Now start a coordinate system:
[image]

One can see immediately that the action of $R_{1}$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
D(R_{1})\mathbf{e}_{x} & = & -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{e}_{x} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \mathbf{e}_{y} ,\quad
D(R_{1})\mathbf{e}_{y} & = & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \mathbf{e}_{x} - \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{e}_{y} ,\quad
D(R_{1})\mathbf{e}_{z} & = & \mathbf{e}_{z}
\end{eqnarray}
Or
\begin{eqnarray}
D(R_{1}) = \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

This representation is reducible (look into the $2\times 2$ block). Do the same for the rest of the transformations, which will immediately give the matrices you are asking.